# Exception from Kafka consuming when one broker service is down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

we have Kafka production cluster with 3 nodes , when replication factor set to 3

we noticed about the following problem ( **PIC 1** ) when one of Kafka brokers service is down

lets say Kafka broker02 is down , and all other brokers services are up

we also verified the brokers leaders on the relevant partitions and we approved that all brokers leaders are assignments successfully to all topic partitions , its mean the broker that is down not assignment but all others are assignments to 5 partitions

what is interesting is that we get the following exception from Kafka consumer side

**PIC 1**

```
LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE
ERROR [driver][][] [org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution] Query APP_SOD [id = ba85bb112-8656de-4857c-b7ea-2856bac0dd3e56, runId = 19c908b0-1149-40d3-8e5b-a4918271a65d] terminated with errororg.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition battery-topic-for-cars-3 could be determined
```

we have the topic - partition `battery-topic-for-cars` , and this topic has 5 partitions

but the exception as I explained above comes from consumer when one of the brokers is down ,

as all know when we have 3 Kafka brokers , then its normal behavior that one broker can be down for example for maintenance propose

so what we need to improve in order to avoid such of this exception ?

```
terminated with errororg.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timeout of 60000ms expired before the position for partition battery-topic-for-cars-3 could be determined
```

here is example from Kafka topic described when one broker is down ( in this case its broker 01 )

```
Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   PartitionCount: 5       ReplicationFactor: 3    Configs: segment.bytes=1073741824,retention.ms=1917196682
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 0    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1002,1003
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 1    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1002,1003
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 2    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1003,1002
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 3    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1002,1003
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 4    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1002,1003
        Topic: battery-topic-for-cars   Partition: 5    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1003,1002
```

Comment: What is your consumer's `metadata.max.age.ms` config value? The error indicates the leader broker is down or is not yet elected.

Comment: I think we have the default value we not touch this parameter

Comment: why you suspect this parameter?

Comment: Because `LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE` indicates leader down, and usually it can 'choose' another leader, but if its maximum age of getting metadata is less, then it could not get enough time to elect another leader, and then it throws this exception. I'm not 100% sure, but that's how I suspect it is.

Comment: If you can test it in your prod, our any other way to 'simulate' this situation, try putting in a larger value.

Comment: the default value - 300000 ( metadata.max.age.ms ) , so you suggested to increase it ? , 5min isn't enough ?

Comment: I was not aware of its default value. I can assume it is enough. The problem is we don't have leader available. You have automatic leader election enabled (it is enabled by default)? Maybe check `unclean.leader.election.enable` broker config whether is True or not. Retry mechanisms?

Comment: in my kafka I can see auto.leader.rebalance.enable=true

Comment: and unclean.leader.election.enable=false , in my kafka configuration

Comment: Yes, we found the culprit. Since this is false, it will only elect a new leader for a partition when all of the replicas for that partition are available. I suspect this was set to be on the safer side on replication/syncs b/w leader and others.

Comment: so you recommended to set unclean.leader.election.enable to true ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253436/discussion-between-judy-and-jishan-shaikh).

Comment: as you know set unclean.leader.election.enable to true , can cause maybe data loss , so the question is if we set this parameter to true with replica 3 , do you think we are in risk about data loss?

Comment: There's always risk for data loss, but it starts with your producer. If you set acks=none or acks=1, then the leader partition that the producer writes to crashes, then you'll lose that data completely unless the producer retries to write to another node while that happens. In either case, there's no replicas and no consumer able to see those events from the leader... Meanwhile the consumer will reconnect to a different leader

Comment: so maybe in order to minimize the risk we can increase the replica from 3 to 4 - what you think about ?